# use of git command outside of C: drive in cmd prompt

Tags: git, cmd

I'm using windows 7 and I have Git installed. When using git command in the cmd.exe while in any directory in C: everything fine. As soon as I switch to another drive. I get prompted with "'git' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file." when trying to use the git command.

I know this is more of a question of how windows command line works and not programming but any help would be awesome.

Comment: What's the value of your `%PATH%`?

Comment: You should install git with bash terminal in it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should install git with bash terminal in it, if you do so you don't need to use the windows command prompt. Here is a nice link for it, I am also using git on windows and I never used the windows command prompt I use git bash and it gives me the feel that I am working on linux machine as it understands "ls".

[Using git bash in windows](https://openhatch.org/missions/windows-setup/open-git-bash-prompt)

here is one more 
[Git on windows](http://guides.beanstalkapp.com/version-control/git-on-windows.html)

Some other nice links by a quick search on google :

```
http://msysgit.github.io/
```

And one more

```
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/457305/Basic-Git-Command-Line-Reference-for-Windows-Users
```

For changing directory in windows in git bash

```
http://www.geekgumbo.com/2010/04/22/git-for-windows-changing-directories-part-2/
```

Comment: It worked :). I'm used to Linux command line anyways so I really like this solution.

Answer (score 0):

Check your PATH variable. It's likely that the item in the path that points to the `git` command doesn't have a drive letter designation. So if, for example, it says `...;\Program Files\git;...` in your PATH, it will look in `D:\Program Files\git` if you switch to drive `D:`. Make sure the drive letter is specified in the directory shown in the PATH (*e.g.*, `...;C:\Program Files\git;...`).

Comment: Thank you for a quick response this sounds like it would work as well but I ended up using the other solution.